# Displaying a new list after selecting an item from a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I'm just starting with Android. I've been able to successfully display a list and handle clicks on any particular item. What I want to do is have a new list appear based on what item is clicked.

For example..

```
Florida
Georgia
....
```

User clicks Florida and a new list is displayed...

```
Miami
Tampa
..
```

Should I create a new Activity and handle it that way? For some reason I just can't quite find sample code that covers this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Most common way is to have another activity. In your onItemClick handler you create an Intent, pass in the item you clicked on, and then launch that.

So something like

```
ListView listView = new ListView(this);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Object obj = listView.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
    Intent in = new Intent(FirstListActivity.this, SecondListActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("obj", obj );
    startActivity(in);
}
```

});

Then in your 2nd activity, you can get the object clicked on, and then use that to populate another list view. The advantage of this is that the user can use the undo button to go back to the first list nicely.

Remember the object you are passing must implement Serializable or be a basic type.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Object obj  = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("obj");
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to call `setListAdapter()` with an adapter that has your 2nd list of values once an item in the first list is clicked.

> Should I create a new Activity and
>   handle it that way?

You could definitely go that route, but from your description it sounds like just setting the `ListView` contents to the 2nd set of values would work.