# ListView onItemClick launches another ListView - with Fragments

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment, nested-lists, child-fragment

On startup, my app launches a fragment which displays a listView of 'projects'. When I click on a project, a new fragment is launched which displays the project's details, including another listView of 'tasks' (each project object can contain many tasks).

I am having trouble initializing the arrayadapter for the second listview.
`tasksAdapter = new TasksArrayAdapter(getActivity(),selectedProject.getTasks());`

It wont compile, and Android Studios offers the following reason:

`incompatible types. Required: ProjectsArrayAdapter. Found: TasksArrayAdapter`

the ProjectsArrayAdapter was set up on the previous fragment like so:

```
    //initialize a custom ArrayAdapter to connect the object to the listView

    projectsAdapter = new ProjectsArrayAdapter(getActivity(), Projects.getInstance().getProjects());
    projectsList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewProjects);

    projectsList.setAdapter(projectsAdapter);

    //=========================================================================================
    //when you click on a project from the list
    //=========================================================================================

    //create onClickListener for listView items and launch project details fragment on click

    projectsList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            FragmentProject myProject = new FragmentProject();

            //grab the object you clicked on
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("ARG_POSITION", position);
            myProject.setArguments(args);

            //launch project details fragment
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.main_layout, myProject);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

**Why cant I create this new array adapter?**

Comment: This one is still stumping me. I'm quite sure the second parameter (the arraylist) is not the issue. I think it has something to do with the context already being used by the projects arrayadapter.

Comment: Is it the case that each activity can only have one ListView (or one list view adapter)? Perhaps I wont have this problem if I use a Child Fragment. In that case:
Fragment with list of projects is populated. The user clicks on a project, and a child fragment showing project details and a listView of tasks is launched.

Comment: The following post suggests that what I'm trying to do is possible, although I would rather use a new fragment than a new activity since it will be more flexible across devices.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575132/displaying-a-new-list-after-selecting-an-item-from-a-listview-in-android

Comment: The fact that this doesnt seem to be a problem to anyone else suggests that I must have just made a silly mistake somewhere, but I cant see any such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because tasksAdapter was declared as a ProjectsArrayAdapter instead of a TasksArrayAdapter- a copy/paste error.

`static TasksArrayAdapter tasksAdapter;`